# Run dart script outside of a project folder

Tags: dart

I am trying to replace python with dart as a scripting language for my tools. I can create a python file anywhere, import global packages and run it but I can't seem to get this working with dart. Do I always need a pubspec.yaml file to run a dart script?

This is the script I am trying to run:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main(List<String> args) async{
  var res = await http.get('https://example.com');
  print(res.headers);
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.
test2.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'package:http/http.dart'
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
       ^
test2.dart:4:19: Error: Method not found: 'get'.
  var res = await http.get('https://example.com');
```

Comment: The answer is yes!

Comment: If you compile your script with `dart2native` you can run it anywhere as standalone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't *need* a *pubspec.yaml* file to *run* a program, but it does need to somehow be able to resolve all the imports.

The *pubspec.yaml* file is used for obtaining the packages (from pub.dev, a git repository, etc.) but not for finding the packages at runtime. The `pub` program reads the *pubspec.yaml* file and downloads the packages mentioned in it, and maintains a packages specification file indicating where each package resolves to. By default the packages specification is in a file called `.packages` in the same directory as the *pubspec.yaml* file. The Dart runtime normally finds the packages by looking at the `.packages` package specification file, but there are other ways.

Here are some options:

1. Put a `.packages` file in the same directory as the Dart program, or in an ancestor directory.
2. Use the `--packages` option to specify the package specification file to use:

   ```
   dart --packages=/home/username/stuff/mypackagespecfile  myprogram.dart
   ```
3. The Dart runtime also has a `--package-root` option. But I haven't figured out how to make it work.
4. The import statements use URIs, so `import 'file://...';` can also work in some cases.
5. Use `dart2native` to compile the program into an executable.

---

Note: Dart scripts can also start with a hash-bang line:

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env dart

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main(List<String> args) async{
  var res = await http.get('https://example.com');
  print(res.headers);
}
```

Then you can make the program executable and run it without needing to type in the Dart runtime:

```sh
$ chmod a+x myprogram.dart
$ ./myprogram.dart
```